# Vector Field Exponential Map

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, vector-fields

I've got ${\bf v} = x^2\partial_x$, and I'm trying to find $\exp(\varepsilon{\bf v})$, but I'm having some trouble.

If I define ${\bf v}^{n+1} = {\bf v}{\bf v}^n$ then I get a different outcome to ${\bf v}^{n+1} = {\bf v}^n{\bf v}$.

For example:

$${\bf v}^2 = {\bf vv} = (x^2\partial_x)(x^2\partial_x) = x^2(\partial_xx^2)\partial_x = 
x^2(2x)\partial_x = 2x^3\partial_x$$

$${\bf v}^3 = {\bf v}{\bf v}^2 =(x^2\partial_x)(2x^3\partial_x)=x^2(\partial_x2x^3)\partial_x = x^2(6x^2)\partial_x = 6x^4\partial_x$$
$${\bf v}^3 = {\bf v}^2{\bf v} = (2x^3\partial_x)(x^2\partial_x) = 2x^3(\partial_xx^2)\partial_x = 2x^3(2x)\partial_x = 4x^4\partial_x$$

Using ${\bf v}^{n+1} = {\bf v}{\bf v}^n$ gives 
$$\exp(\varepsilon {\bf v})x = \frac{x}{1-\varepsilon x}$$

While using ${\bf v}^{n+1} = {\bf v}^n{\bf v}$ gives
$$\exp(\varepsilon {\bf v})x = \frac{x}{2}(1+\mathrm e^{2\varepsilon x})$$

In both cases, when $\varepsilon =0$, we get just $x$, i.e. the identity element. Also, in both cases, we get
$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\varepsilon} \exp(\varepsilon {\bf v})x = {\bf v}$$

The same ${\bf v} \in \mathfrak g$ can't possible generate two different flows, can it?

Comment: Doesn't it seem odd to you that you are not getting iterates (i.e. nested compositions) of $\partial_x$?  For instance, if $\mathbf{v} = \partial_x$, what should $\mathbf{v}^2$ be?

Comment: If ${\bf v} = \partial_x$ then I would say ${\bf v}^2 = (1\partial_x)(1\partial_x) = 1(\partial_x 1)\partial_x=0$. Similarly ${\bf v}^n =0$ for all $n \ge 2$, meaning that $\exp(\varepsilon {\bf v})x= (1+\varepsilon \partial_x)x=x+\varepsilon$, which is the correct flow.

Comment: And yet, "the derivative with respect to $x$ of the derivative with respect to $x$" is not the zero operator (without projection to first order operators).  If $\mathbf{v} = \partial_x$, $\mathbf{v}^2 = \partial_x^2$, the second derivative with respect to $x$.  (... which projects onto the zero vector on the subspace of first order differentials.)  But in short, in your expression "$1(\partial_x 1) \partial_x$", you have made an error: the first $\partial_x$ acts on the *rest* of the expression; you should have "$1 \partial_x (1 \partial_x) = 1 (1 \partial_x^2 + 0 \partial_x)$".

Answer (score 1):

If you apply the product rule carefully, you don't get two different answers.  In your example, \begin{align*}
\mathbf{v}(f(x)) &= (x^2 \partial_x)(f(x))  \\
    &= x^2 f'(x)  \text{, and }\\
\mathbf{v}^2(f(x)) &= (x^2 \partial_x)\left( (x^2 \partial_x)(f(x)) \right)  \\
    &= (x^2 \partial_x)\left( x^2 f'(x) \right)  \\
    &= x^2(2x f'(x) + x^2 f''(x) )  \text{, or } \\
\mathbf{v}^2(f(x)) &= \left((x^2 \partial_x) (x^2 \partial_x) \right) (f(x))  \\
    &= (x^2(2x \partial_x + x^2 \partial_x^2))(f(x))  \\
    &= x^2(2x f'(x) + x^2 f''(x) )
\end{align*}
so we see $\mathbf{v}^2 = 2x^3 \partial_x + x^4 \partial_x^2$.  Similarly, $\mathbf{v}^3 = 6 x^4 \partial_x + 6 x^5 \partial_x^2 + x^6 \partial_x^3$.

(Of course, if we're linearizing, we project onto the first term in both of those.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Am I right to think that ${\bf v}$ is best understood by its action on a function, i.e. ${\bf v}(f)$, and so "multiplying on the right" doesn't make sense. ${\bf v}[{\bf v}(f)]$ is fine, while $[{\bf v}(f)]{\bf v}$ doesn't make sense because it's not a function. Hence ${\bf v}^{n+1} = {\bf v}{\bf v}^n$ is the only way to go?

Comment: @FlybyNight : $[\mathbf{v}(f)]\mathbf{v}$ is an operator as much as $x^2 \partial_x$ is since $\mathbf{v}(f)$ is some function and the $\mathbf{v}$ on the right still has an open slot to consume a function.  Note that I showed both $\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{v}(f))$ and $(\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{v}))(f)$ above, so both "wrap another $\mathbf{v}$ on the left" ($\mathbf{v} (\mathbf{v}^n(f))$) and "let $\mathbf{v}^n$ act on $\mathbf{v}(f)$" ($\mathbf{v}^n (\mathbf{v}(f))$), arriving at the same result both ways.

Comment: But ${\bf v}(f){\bf v}$ isn't a function, while ${\bf vv}(f)$ is. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the simplest [Lie advective flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator) in perturbation theory (as applied in physics: QFT) and the workhorse example in the 19th century book of Georg Sheffer cited.

**v** generates a shift operator, and it pays to define suitable canonical coordinates,
$$
y=-1/x, \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad x^2 \partial_x=\partial_y ,
$$ 
so that you are shifting *y* by $\epsilon$,
$$
e^{\epsilon \partial_y} ~~f(y)= f(y+\epsilon),
$$
which reads
$$
e^{\epsilon x^2\partial_x} ~~g(x)= g\left(\frac{-1}{y+\epsilon}\right )=g\left (\frac{x}{1-\epsilon x}\right ), 
$$
a standard formula in the RG advection of QFT.

Your difficulties are traceable to your refusal to perform your [Heaviside calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_calculus) manipulations of functions of differential operators with a "test-function" *f(x)* on the right, which keeps track of the proper chain rule action of noncommuting derivative operators.

Answer (score 0):

The action of a vector field as a derivation on the space of functions means that it only makes sense to multiply on the left because ${\bf v}(f)$ is a function and so ${\bf v}[{\bf v}(f)]$ is also a function, while $[{\bf v}(f)]{\bf v}$ is a function times a vector field, i.e. a vector field.

The differential operator ${\bf v} = x^2\partial_x$ is best understood as *differentiate with respect to $x$, and then multiply by $x^2$*.

Applied to $x$, we get $x \mapsto 1 \mapsto x^2$, meaning ${\bf v}(x) = x^2$.

Applied to $x^2$, we get $x^2 \mapsto 2x \mapsto 2x^3$, meaning ${\bf v^2}(x) = 2x^3$.

Applied to $2x^3$, we get $2x^3 \mapsto 6x^2 \mapsto 6x^4$, meaning ${\bf v}^3(x) = 6x^4$.

In general, ${\bf v}^n(x) = n!x^{n+1}$, and so for all $|\varepsilon x|<1$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{\varepsilon^n}{n!}{\bf v}^n(x) &=& \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{\varepsilon^n}{n!}n!x^{n+1} \\ \\
&=& x\sum_{n \ge 0} (\varepsilon x)^n \\ \\
&=& \frac{x}{1-\varepsilon x}
\end{eqnarray*}